# Fixing serverless typescript, Types of property 'event' are incompatible?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

I've upgraded to serverless 3, running typescript. There is a type match error in the serverless configuration files since.

Partially my serverless.ts file is

```
const serverlessConfiguration: Serverless = {
service: 'hello',
frameworkVersion: '3',
useDotenv: true,

plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-domain-manager', 'serverless-iam-roles-per-function', 'serverless-certificate-creator'],
provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    region: 'ap-southeast-2',
    apiGateway: {
        minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
        shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
        AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
    },
},
functions: {hello},
custom: {
```

There is something wrong with the schema of hello/index.ts file is

```
import schema from './schema';
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handlerResolver';

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
   {
     http: {
       method: 'post',
       path: 'hello',
       private: false,
       request: {
         schemas: {
           'application/json': schema
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ]
```

}

I've read that http.request.schema has been replaced by [http.request.schemas](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations)

The error message I'm getting is

```
  Type '{ schemas: { 'application/json': { readonly type: "object"; readonly properties: { readonly name: { readonly type: "string"; }; }; readonly required: readonly ["name"]; }; }; }' has no properties in common with type 'HttpRequestValidation'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package @types/serverless has the wrong specification

Remove this package

```
npm remove @types/serverless
```

Add the serverless typescript package

```
npm i -D @serverless/typescript
```

Change the import in serverless.ts from

```
import type {Serverless} from 'serverless/aws';
```

to

```
import type {AWS} from "@serverless/typescript";
```

Make sure that *index.ts* has *scheams* and not *schema*.

The final index.ts file is as above

[Ref](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations)